# gcc: mixing __builtin_expect and noreturn

Tags: c++, gcc

On a big project I'm working on, we tend to use gcc's __builtin_expect in our error checking (usually when that error is going to abort the current operation):

```
if( __builtin_expect( failed, 0 ) )
    // handle error and fail
```

on the other hand, we have a (small) set of centralized error functions that deal with certain error types (i.e.: a consumer has run out of data).

Those functions all end by throwing an exception, so they never return.

This leaves our error checking as :

```
if( __builtin_expect( got_bytes, 0 ) )
    customError( NoDataErrorCode, "No more data" ) ; // <-- always throws an exception
```

To avoid a few warnings I get here and there, I decided to mark those functions as noreturn.

By reading gcc's documentation for both __builtin_expect and noreturn I understand there should be no problem with that, but you never know.

I've written a small test program:

```
#include <stdexcept>

void throwIt( void ) __attribute__( ( noreturn ) ) ;

void throwIt( bool )
{
    throw std::runtime_error( "forced error" ) ;
}

void iffail( bool failed )
{
    if( __builtin_expect( failed, 0 ) )
        throwIt( failed ) ;
}

int main( int argc, char ** )
{
    iffail( !!( argc & 1 ) ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Compiling it with -O3 -S and checking the assembly code I found out that both the builtin and the attribute are irrelevant in this particular case. Removing any (or both) of them produces exactly the same assembly code. This leaves me wondering if __builtin_expect has any effect on a simple if statement with a simple function call in it.

NOTE: The bool argument to throwIt is there to force the compiler to do something more than just calling the function inside the if.

So my question is: Is this arrangement safe or will there be a case in which this will bite back.

Comment: Disclaimer:  I'm no gcc hacker.  I believe `noreturn` tells the compiler that it is impossible for the function to return.  It's a semantic assertion that can lead to wrong code if misused---returning from a `noreturn` function is UB or something.  (I'm not sure whether throwing an exception counts as returning for `noreturn` purposes, which seems central to your question.  `longjmp` is `noreturn`, though...)  `__builtin_expect` just tells the compiler about branch probabilities; it doesn't affect the program's meaning.

Comment: @tmyklebu As per gcc's own documentation, you can throw in a noreturn function.

Comment: [Apparently it's okay to throw from a `_Noreturn`](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/09/understanding-attributes/): "used to tell the compiler that a function will not return (note that throwing an exception is not the same thing as returning)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. As explained below, it may or may not make a difference to the actual code.

The PURPOSE of the `__attribute__(noreturn`) and `__builtin_expect` is to help the compiler.

The noreturn atrribute avoid warnings for "function returns without return statement" if you do something like:

```
void panic(const char *msg) __atrribute__(noreturn);

int func(int x)
{

   if (x < 0) 
       panic("x must not be negative");
   else
       return x * 42;
}
```

(Of course, in this particular case, the `else` is completely superfluous - but I'm sure we could come up with an example where this sort of thing happens and the return doesn't exist)

the expect "function" helps the compiler understand that "this is likely to happen" or "this is unlikely to happen", and the compiler will pick the "best path" based on if it's likely or not, for example:

```
if (failed)
   throwIt( failed );
```

now, if the compiler is thinking that failed is likely, it would generate code like this:

```
if (!failed) goto not_failed;

throwIt( failed );

not_failed:
do_other_stuff();
```

where as if the compiler thinks that it's unlikely that failed is true:

```
if (failed) goto do_failed;

do_other_stuff();
return;

do_failed:
throwIt( failed );
```

(Many processors also have bits to tell the branch prediction unit to "prime" with "this is predicted to be true" or "this is predicted to be false", which may also get encoded into the code in the first and second case if you use __builtin_expect).

Of course, in your case, it may well be that the compiler "guesses" that an inlined throw is an unlikely scenario without hints, and thus generates the same piece of code either way. Or that it just "by coincidence" comes up with such code anyway.

Also, different processors, as well as target backends of gcc, are more or less sophisticated, so depending on exactly which target is being compiled for, the difference may vary greatly between some processor and another.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation. This was my understanding prior to posting this question, but I felt it was better to ask.

Comment: Incidentally, what triggered all this was a "no return value" warning: A function has to iterate over all available devices and return the first one that matches a certain criteria; if it reaches the end of the function without finding any suitable one it hits the panic button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it. The primary purpose of `__builtin_expect` is to act as a hint to the compiler that helps it to generate better branch prediction code. The effect might be highly sensitive to the target CPU type, since different CPU's have quite different branch prediction heuristics. The compiler might completely ignore branch-prediction-based optimizations anywhere outside some pre-determined and easily recognizable execution patterns, like a conditional jump inside a tight loop.

The purpose of `noreturn` is to suppress some compile-time warnings and, when opportunity arises, to eliminate dead code.

These features will affect the generated code if the circumstances are right for it. It just so happens that your program does not create any opportunities for these features to make any difference.

Comment: `noreturn` does way more than just "suppress some compile-time warnings and eliminate dead code."  It changes the semantics of your program.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Firstly, no it does not do "way more". Secondly, the exact semantics of `noreturn` is completely irrelevant within the context of the question. And thirdly, no, it does not change the semantics of the program, if used as intended.

Comment: The key there is "...if used as intended."  If you make a sufficiently bad mistake, the compiler will happily optimise away live code and possibly do something much worse.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Maybe, but that bears no relevance to the topic.

Comment: Dude, this question is *about* the semantics of `__builtin_expect` and `noreturn`.  The semantics of `noreturn` are *central* to the question.  That `noreturn` asserts to the compiler that a function cannot possibly return, even if the compiler is unable to prove it, is the *whole purpose* of `noreturn`.  And that's why it can lead to the elimination of live code if used correctly.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Er... Taken literally, this question is: why the generated code does not change (with an induced sub-question of whether it is OK to mix `__builtin_expect` and `noreturn`). In order to answer it there's no need to dump the full semantics of those features into the answer. (Not even mentioning that 1) my description actually does accurately describe the full semantics of `noreturn`, 2) neither feature does not provide an exhaustive specification.)

Comment: @AndreyT, I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but the intention is just the opposite: My question is if combining both features is safe; and while trying to investigate it I stumbled upon the case in which the compiler generated exactly the same code.

Comment: @AndreyT: In order to handle your interpretation of the question, you just need to run the code and check that it does what it's intended to do.  And no, you don't accurately describe the full semantics of `noreturn` in your answer.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I'm not sure what you mean by "handle" in the first part of your comment. As for `noreturn`... my description of `noreturn` semantics matches that from GCC documentation and, more importantly, my own experience with the feature. So, yes it does accurately describe it.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yet it is incomplete, as I noted earlier.  Why are you refusing to recognise this simple fact?

Comment: @tmyklebu: Firstly, the description in my answer is too informal to be definitively deemed "incomplete". I think it is rather clear and obvious that that informal description can be stretched to cover almost anything and is "complete" in that sense. I don't see the point in doing that, but you for some reason keep steering the discussion in that direction. Secondly, it was never my intent to present the formal description of `noreturn` semantics in my answer. But I already covered all that in my first comments.